# Is it possible to restore RBAC/Users on an Azure subscription after transferring it to another tenant?

Tags: azure, subscription, transfer, rbac, loss

As part of a tenant migration, one of our users migrated an Azure subscription from one tenant to another. All RBAC dropped off (as expected), but they did not take note of the user & roles prior to transfer.

Is it possible to obtain a cached role/config view of an Azure subscription or once it is transferred, is it completely wiped?

Comment: I could not find any official doc about it, may be you could [contact azure support for help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request).